# Was the name "Thanos" derived from "Thanatos", the name of the Greek god of death?

Tags: marvel, names, inspiration, thanos, greek-myth

*This is intended to be an out-of-universe question*

I recently learned of [Thanatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanatos) the Greek god of death, and I could not help but notice how similar the name Thanos is to the name Thanatos. This got me wondering if the original writers did this intentionally, especially considering Thanos' relationship with and association to death (and [Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(Marvel_Comics))) in the comics.

Is there any indication that the similarity in names between Thanatos and Thanos is more than coincidence?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/thanos-got-name-horrifying-way-explained/#:~:text=In%20Greek%2C%20the%20name%20%E2%80%9CThanos,name%20literally%20means%20%E2%80%9Cdeath.%E2%80%9D

Comment: Bonus: In Greek, the name Thanos is real and it is commonly used in modern times. It is one of a few possible shortenings of the name Athanasios, which means "immortal".

Comment: seems a little weird if it would be in-universe, so i wouldn't have thought to have to make the disclaimer at the start. but eh, better safe than sorry i guess.

Comment: @SigmaOri i am inevitable. i am iron man. i am immortal.

Comment: @SigmaOri Though removing that 'A' at the beginning completely negates the meaning of the word of course.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman But it does result in an existing Modern Greek word, which is actually a remarkably strong influence in many languages on the formation of nicknames.

Comment: @BCLC Well, Valorum’s comment points to a link that implies it could be in-universe (something I was not expecting).

Comment: Notice that Wikipedia's entry marks Thanatos as " the personification of death". Hades was "the god of the dead and the king of the underworld". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hades

Comment: Hi! Greek guy here, just randomly reading this. @SigmaOri correctly mentions the popular shortening Athanasios => Thanos (Αθανάσιος => Θάνος). While it's true that Athanasios is derived from the word "athanasia" (αθανασία, immortality) and also that Athanasia is itself a name in Greek (the female form of Athanasios), "Athanasios" does not in itself mean anything. The word for "immortal" is athanatos / athanati (αθάνατος / αθάνατη) for males and females respectively.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, "Thanos" is indeed derived from the name "Thanatos", the name of the Freudian concept of [death drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive) (which in turn is named after the Thanatos of myth), according to [Vulture](https://www.vulture.com/2019/04/jim-starlin-creator-of-infinity-war-thanos-hates-marvel.html):

> While attending a psychology class in junior college in order to woo a woman, Starlin had become briefly acquainted with the Freudian concept of Thanatos, humanity’s drive for death and self-destruction. As a result, even before he started at Marvel, he’d drawn up plans for a villain named Thanos, using that subtracted spelling “because it ‘looked’ better in print.”